# EXCEL VBA Code to generate serial numbers from a range

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWiHG.png)Please i am new to Vba.

1. Please I want a VBA that generates serial numbers from data entered in A1 and B2. The result should be in another sheet Column A.
2. When I enter another range in A2 and B2, the serial numbers should continue at where the first serial numbers ended.

   Inline image

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143262/excel-sequential-numbers-specified-start-and-end-values-shift-column-data-d

Comment: I got a code from this website that is close to what i want but the old serial numbers keep repeating any time i run a new serial numbers. The second code "Sub sof20143262Serial_numbers()"

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you're trying to achieve or anything? I just don't know how to help you.. [This is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360611/vba-code-to-auto-serial-number-in-column-a-after-my-userform-entered-data-in-col/39376327#39376327) that I did for someone who had a question regarding building serial numbers with strings, maybe you can tailor it to meet your needs or further describe what parts of it you can't get to work for you.

Comment: It does not. I have updated with screen shot of what i want to achieve. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out and let me know if it works for you.. This will provide you with the results shown in your picture.

```
    Sub SerialCode()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startOf As Long, endOf As Long, data 'startOf and endOf are Long for >5 digits.
    Dim lastRow As Long, currentRow As Long
    Dim dataRange As Range, c As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    ws.Range("E2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Clear
    ws.Range("F2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Clear
    lastRow = 2
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))


    For Each c In dataRange
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            currentRow = c.Row
            startOf = CLng(ws.Range("A" & currentRow).Value)
            endOf = CLng(ws.Range("B" & currentRow).Value) + 1

            If endOf <> 1 And startOf < endOf Then 'This will stop Overflow errors from occuring accidently
                data = ws.Range("C" & currentRow).Value

                Do While startOf <> endOf
                    ws.Range("E" & lastRow).Value = startOf
                    ws.Range("F" & lastRow).Value = data
                    startOf = startOf + 1
                    lastRow = lastRow + 1
                Loop

            Else: MsgBox "Ending Serial Number missing or is less than starting Serial Number on row " _
                & c.Row, vbCritical, "Missing Data"
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Gives compile error, object required at line 6 "Set lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1"

Comment: @eka24 I fixed the code, try the updated code in my answer. (I'm at my computer now and was able to test it)

Comment: It run and produced the result but old range serial numbers keep repeating. I want the code to avoid running old number that has been run already. example if i have 11-13 which produces 11, 12, 13. when i enter another range like 101-103, it should give 11, 12, 13, 101, 102, 103. but as the code stands, it gives 11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13,101, 102, 103, repeating already produced serial numbers. The serial numbers are unique and cannot be run twice. it should run current range if range has been run already. Thanks for your effort so far Tyeler

Comment: @eka24 I'm not sure how it would run repeating numbers.. The For loop only goes through the cells once, and the line `ws.Range("E2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Clear` deletes all the original results prior to the code running. Does it only repeat the first instance? I can't seem to recreate what you're talking about on my side..

Comment: well i will manage it like that by manually deleting the old range which repeats when new range is run. Thanks very much

Comment: Well.. I would like to answer your question if you can help me understand it better...

Comment: Please run 11-13. After that enter another range 20-23. Do not put both ranges before you run the code. You will get 11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23 which is wrong because i dont expect duplicates. I expect this result; 11, 12, 13, 20, 21, 22, 23. run the first range 11-13. later, enter the second range 20-21 without deleting the first range 11-13 you entered.

Comment: @eka24 Okay! I rewrote a couple portions of the code, and threw in an overflow error preventer via `If statement`. The updated code is in my answer. Let me know if any part of this isn't doing what you think it should. This should get you started on a final product. I believe this also answers the question entirely, so if you could mark it as such that'd be great!

Comment: Exactly what am looking for. Great work Tyeler, thanks

Comment: sorry for coming back. I get overflow error for 6 digit numbers like 333901. it works for less digit serial numbers like 21. Any help to avoid the overflow error for big numbers?

Comment: Yes. The reason you're getting an overflow is because `CInt()` can only handle -32768 to 32767. To avoid that, change `startOf` and `endOf` to Long, and change `CInt` to `CLng`. I've updated the code to reflect this change if you want to see where I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks, is working

Comment: Please is there a way allow a single number like 566163 to be added to the list of numbers generated. currently if the numbers are not in a range like 555666-600001 the code will not accept.

Comment: There's a very simple way to do that without changing the code at all. Just make your starting number and ending numbers the same. So for your example, Starting No would be 566163 and Ending No would be 566163. That will put just a single number with it's data to your list.

Comment: ok thanks you  very much

Comment: Please the code above works perfectly in excel as I requested. I need help on how to use same procedure in access. Thus what would be the access vba for the same procedure of generating serial numbers based on a given range.

Comment: I wish I could tell you but I'm only familiar with using Excel